# Read image file in Image object from zip file

Tags: c#, winforms, zip

I'm using `iconic.dll` file to read data from compressed files (.zip file extensions)

Please check my code below

```
string zippath = txtFilePath.Text.Trim() + "\\" + foldername + ".zip";
ArrayList arrFiles = new ArrayList();
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(enrollment))
{
     foreach (ZipEntry e1 in zip)
     {
       arrFiles.Add(e1.ToString());
     }
}

foreach (string path in arrFiles)
{
   Image img1 = Image.FromFile(path);  //geting error on this line
   imageList.Images.Add(getThumbnaiImage(imageList.ImageSize.Width, img1));
}
```

How can I read image files from a compressed folder?

Comment: Use the ZipEntry.OpenReader() method.  And pass the stream it returns to Image.FromStream().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the solution:

```
  using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(enrollment))
        {

            foreach (ZipEntry e1 in zip)
            {

                    CrcCalculatorStream reader = e1.OpenReader();
                    MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
                    reader.CopyTo(memstream);
                    byte[] bytes = memstream.ToArray();
                    Image img1 = Image.FromStream(memstream);
                    imageList.Images.Add(getThumbnaiImage(imageList.ImageSize.Width, img1));


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(enrollment))
{
    ZipEntry entry = zip["Image.bmp"];
    entry.Extract(outputStream);
}
```

Also you can show your image in a pricturebox :

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        var bmp = new Bitmap(outputStream);
        pb.Image = bmp;
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
```

Comment: @LajjaThaker it's the place for output of extracted image files.

Comment: Can you write a line that declare outputStream  object